# Empty vector menu in QGIS on PC with French as default language

Tags: qgis, vector, internationalization

I installed QGIS 3.0.0 on a PC with French as default language. After changing the language of QGIS to English, the 'Vector' menu is empty and there is a French 'Vecteur' menu.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I cannot change the system language.

Comment: What happens if you run the OSGeo4W Shell (e.g. `Start menu > All programs > QGIS 3.0 > OSGeo4W Shell`) and type in `qgis --lang en`?

Comment: Related to [Incomplete raster menu in QGIS3](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276229/incomplete-raster-menu-in-qgis3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is already a [bug reported](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18202) for this problem.

In the meantime you can click "Reset to defaults" under Settings > Options > Processing and then restart QGIS. This removes the empty vector/raster menus.

Comment: Using QGIS 3.2 (Bonn), I do not have a Processing option when I go Settings > Options.

Comment: ... I don't have a processing option in the Settings>Options either... both in 3.16 and 3.18. I was operating 3.14 (I think) on the same laptop and had no problem...

Comment: I didn't have that option either, but I think that is because this is a different error. The OP's error was not the lack of the menu but that it was duplicated (french and english) and he only needed to remove the unused/empty one. My error was that I only had one empty menu. The processing tools were not loaded at all and that is why I didn't have the option under Settings, once loaded I do have it. Julio's answer below was the correct answer to my problem but not for the OP's.

Comment: I have a "processing" option and a "reset to defaults" button. But there's an error when I click it.

Answer (score 12):

I'm teaching qgis right now and several student have the same problem. The processing plugin deactivate by their self in several laptops. Just go to plugins/manage and install plugins and reactivate it

Comment: This was the root cause when my Vector menu disappeared.

Comment: This seems to be the most relevant answer for QGIS 3

Comment: This worked for me when I disabled and then re-enabled the processing plugin.