# Incomplete raster menu in QGIS3

Tags: mac, qgis-3

My QGIS3 raster menu seems to be incomplete:

[image]

Analysys, projections, extraction, and all other items are not present, only calculator, align and georeferencer are...
I'm on OSX 10.11.6. Reinstalling or new profile does not work.

---

Well, I don't know why but there are two raster menus in my QGIS3 installation.

[image]

In this second menu item all things seems to be on position. Any idea why this behavior occurs? Any way to join both menus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue, as well as other variants of it, has been reported [here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17448). It has to do with the locale you've selected, and certain menu items not translating properly. As Asier Sarasua reports:

> Trying other languages, I noticed the issue appears in languages where the string "&Raster" is NOT translated exactly as "&Raster". The problem is in languages with other translations (R&aster, &Ráster, &Rasterra, &Rastra...).

### Solutions:

1. Some users report that selecting "Settings > Options > Processing > Reset to Defaults" and restarting QGIS solves this problem. For some, however, this does not work.
2. You can also fix this in "Options > Processing" as follows:

   1. Find the menu items normally in your toolbar under the "Menus" section of this screen.
   2. Expand the given item, and double-click on the "Menu Path" field.
   3. Replace the listed menu path with the appropriate menu designation.
   4. Restart QGIS.

Here's the menu settings screen:

[image: menu modification]

Not only can you use this to put your functions back into the correct menu, you can use it to create *new* menus or rearrange items to your liking. For example, I've here moved the Aspect tool from the Raster menu to a new "Custom" menu bar.

[image: custom menu]

I use this function to keep frequently-used algorithms close at hand, and also to declutter menus of items I do not use, but it can be an effective solution to this problem if "reset to defaults" does not solve this for you.