# Changing language settings on QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, internationalization

I'm using Window 10 Japanese OS. I would like to change the settings (menus etc.) of QGIS 3.0.1 from the default Japanese into English. I tried below but it wouldn't work.

[image: Screenshot of Options]

Comment: QGIS 3.0 seems to have some issues with changing the language, as in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272750/empty-vector-menu-in-qgis-3-0-0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the same dialog, go to the first tab on the top with the screw driver and the hammer called `General`.
Then, it's the first box. Toggle the first checkbox and choose your flag.

You need to restart QGIS.

[image: Language in QGIS 3]