# QGIS - Translation problems

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, internationalization

I've enabled Processing plugin and provided compiled i8n file but somehow there is a error which causes GUI to create two separate buttons. One of them is translated and one is not. Does anybody know what may cause this problem ?

[image: Visualisation of error]

Comment: Can you show what is inside vektor and vector?

Comment: First one is empty and the other one have all necessary functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that issue posted by me is a duplicate of this one: [Empty vector menu in QGIS 3.0.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272750/empty-vector-menu-in-qgis-3-0-0) . Mentioned ticked includes solution. As far as i know this bug still occures. Additional solutions may be find here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18202 .